# Cannot find MySql 5.6.17 dependency in central Maven repo

Tags: maven

I have a Spring/Maven/Hibernate/MySQL application. I am working with the recent release 5.6.17 for MySql. Can someone please point  me to mysql 5.6.17 pom file for maven. I cannot find it in the central repo. Thanks. P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you're trying to add the correct version of **MySQL's Connector/J** library to your project, which would allow you to access your MySQL database from code.

If that's the case, just add this to your project's `pom` file, under `dependencies`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.30</version>
</dependency>
```

This version (5.1.30) of Connector/J was released [March 31, 2014](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-j/en/news-5-1-30.html). The similar version numbers might be confusing, but this is most likely the version of the Connector/J library you want.

More information about the Maven dependency [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.30).

**EDIT:** And because you're using Hibernate, you'll want to set `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` as the `connection.driver_class` in your Hibernate configuration.

Comment: Many thanks, that worked. You are right I was using 5.6.17 connector-java instead of the 5.1.3, since 5.6.17 was the msi installer I used to install mysql.